# Methods which have not been tested in Spring MVC project

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I have developed a system in Java using Spring and hibernate. I have a very young programmer with me and he has developed new methods in the existing classes. My question is related to JUnit testing. Is there any tool which can identified the methods which have no test methods. If I identified those method I can write the rest of the tests for my application.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your tests in your IDE with 'Coverage'. In intelliJ, When you right click on your test folder, you get an option to "Run 'All Tests' with coverage" and it gives you a report on your test coverage. As far as I know, eclipse has something similar as well. Doing this also highlights which lines of your class have been covered by the tests.

Having said that, what you might want to consider using tools like Jacoco or Sonar so you can track overall coverage of your tests as a part of your continuous integration.

Comment: Thanks for help. I am happy with Jacoco.